# Place a button over slidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml

I need to place a button on top of slidingTabLayout. I used layout_below. But, it didn,t work. Please take a look at my XML and fragment code.

```
 <FrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     >

     <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/charge_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/charge" />

     <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
         android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
         android:elevation="1dp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/charge_button"/>


     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/view_pager"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
         android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs">


     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


 </FrameLayout>
```

//Charge is the button name here

[image]

Comment: maybe this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125767/add-button-on-sliding-tab-layout

Answer (score -1):

you must set like this Sorry i had not understood your requirement correctly now got the point you can not overlap layouts you must set title using java code by adding fragments to sliding layout with a title.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37833589/4574463

Comment: I implemented it but now I can't see the SlidingTabLayout strips. I only see the list and a button on the upper right corner. @santosh Kumar

Comment: I have updated my answer you can can try this to achieve the same.

Comment: Let me try. @santosh kumar

Comment: :( i didn't c much change from your previous code output. Except this time there are three buttons.

Comment: Now you can see buttons are above sliding tab layout

Comment: do you want buttons to be placed over sliding layout ?

Comment: yap.@santosh kumar

Comment: I am using a FrameLayout and I can't see the titles of the sliding tabs after implementing your code.

Comment: ooooooo!!!! i get it now... You thought that there are three buttons?? no no,, I said Charge is my only button. Those "all" and "favorite" are the titles of the tabs. @santosh kumar